# Is this behavior (apparently an out of thin air store) forbidden by C11?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, c11

Is the behavior mentioned the [LWN article “Betrayed by a bitfield”](http://lwn.net/Articles/478657/) forbidden by C11? Assume that `spinlock_t` is a type referring to a struct which is accessed only through means of C11 atomic primitives on its members (Actually it uses Linux (the kernel) memory barriers, but assume it doesn't so that it isn't undefined because of using an implementation-specific interface). In addition to the question in the title, is it an example of an “out of thin air store”?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `struct example` case in your link is obviously a compiler bug.

Comment: Generally speaking, if "modified by another processor" is a possibility then the variable (i.e. the spinlock here) should be declared `volatile`. (Maybe the kernel has some extra trickery going on though).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I think that you're confusing volatile with atomic. volatile variables don't have atomicity or synchronization guarantees, see questions that come searching for "C volatile atomic". Do you have a reference to the C11 standard for your claim that it's a compiler bug?. Thanks for answering.

Comment: No I'm not confusing volatile with atomic. And I am fully aware that volatile variables don't have atomicity or synchronization guarantees.

Comment: For the `example` see See 5.1.2.3/6. "The least requirements on a conforming implementation are: — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine."  It's not permitted to read or write a volatile object except specifically as part of an expression that does so.

Comment: Interesting question, I didn't find any reference that would forbid it.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the Linux kernel, but [this page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt) seems to suggest that the spinlock uses a **non-volatile** variable, but correctly written code should only access the lock via a "memory barrier", i.e. `asm volatile` or equivalent. However, the C standard specifies that non-volatile variables follow a memory model that behaves as if there is only one thread; so the compiler is quite fine to read and write the same data back to that variable at any time (or even optimize it out entirely).

Comment: The shared data protected by the spinlock does not need to be volatile , because `asm` introduces implementation-defined behaviour, and gcc (hopefully!) can therefore make it defined behaviour that code within the fence is actually executed within the fence.   However I can't see any reason why the spinlock variable itself should not be `volatile` ... hopefully a kernel expert can clear that up :)

Answer (score 2):

No, as it is presented here it is not forbidden in C11. C11 only makes atomicity guarantees for `_Atomic` types, that is types that you declare within the language as being atomic. Since the kernel uses its own homegrown primitives to ensure atomicity you are on your own, C11 can't help you here.

The thing that changes with C11 `_Atomic` compared to homegrown assembler hacks, is that `_Atomic` may change size and alignment properties of the data type. In the given example, it could for example force the trailing bit field over the edge of the next word boundary.